# Click on button which changes its id everytime

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait, mechanicalsoup

I work with Python and Selenium.
The mission is to click on button with ***text*** '+like' or on column **'td'** with ***class***='profile-image'.
But button hasn't id and it's **class** *'more-likes'* is used in others buttons. Same situation with **div** with ***class*** 'profile-image-button' (div's class id used in others 'divs').
I tried to take id of **'td'** :

```
button = photos.find('td', class_='profile-image')
print(button.get_id)
```

Output is 'None'

Here is html code of webpage:

```html
<div id="category7515692" class="category-content" data-content="present" data-collapsing="true">
  <table class="pictures" data-columns-count="12" data-type="gallery">
    <tbody class="" data-selec="7565904" data-name="beauty" data-live="true">
      <tr data-mutable-id="MR1main" class="header">
        <td class="main-row-buttons" rowspan="1" data-mutable-id="Bmain">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="profile-image" id="view-75634" data-event-more-view="event-more-view" data-selec="7565904" islive="true" isseparatedbutton="false">
                  <div class="profile-image-button">
                    <span class="more-likes">+like</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I click on button or how can I take id?

Comment: Please provide a better example, a real one impossible, so we can test it.

Comment: I've added a big part of html code. Hope it'll help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to click the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.profile-image>div.profile-image-button>span.more-likes"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='profile-image']//span[@class='more-likes' and contains(.,'+like')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I heard something about mechanicalsoup. Could it be the solution? Sorry, I've never worked with it...

Comment: Not aware about _mechanicalsoup_, did you try out the solution? Can I have the status please?

Comment: OH MY GOD! It works! Thank you so much! But it clicks only on one button.I think we identify only 1 button with those parameters. But Webpage has at least 3 buttons. What I should do if I need to click every button? (The thing is... when i click on button, it shows more information that I need to parse too)

Comment: You gotta raise a new question with your new requirement and StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, there is only one button with text '+like', you can search an element with specific text like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '+like')]").click()
```